# GridView1_RowUpdating Error

Tags: asp.net

I am getting this Error:
`'ASP.presentation_show_gridview_aspx'` does not contain a definition for `'GridView1_RowUpdating`' and no extension method `'GridView1_RowUpdating'` accepting a first argument of type `'ASP.presentation_show_gridview_aspx'` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is myCode:

`<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="458px" Height="133px" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">`

Comment: Show the codebehind class `presentation_show_gridview_aspx`. There you have to have a method `GridView1_RowUpdating` which must be  `protected` or `public`.

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView updating.